# Show only English numerical digits in TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I am creating an app which has a login page. In that login page there is a textformfield which accepts only numbers that is if i click on the textformfield it shows only English numbers. But the problem is if the mobile device is in arabic language and click on textformfield it doesn't show English numbers instead it shows arabic numbers in the keyboard. So how to force or show the English numbers in the keyboard even if the mobile phone is in arabic language.

```
TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? mobile : null,
                              controller: mobileNumber,
                              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                                ),
                                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.redAccent),
                                ),
                                hintText: mobile,
                                fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
                                filled: true,
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: have you tried replacing arabic letters with english numerics while user is typing them?

Comment: @HasilT i want to show only English numbers in the mobile keyboard even if the mobile device language is Arabic.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer i use this code inside textfieldform widget. This will help to show English Numerical Numbers even if the mobile device language is different not in English.

```
inputFormatters: [new WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp("[0-9]"))],
```